# Empty data with api Page<E> in spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

```
@RestController
@Transactional
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @RequestMapping(value="/api/category/page", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<Category> getCategoryList() {
        return categoryService.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 10));
    }

}
```

I would like to retrieve the Page  for use in the angularjs, which returns nothing: `{}`. While I `getContent ()` the data is still available on request:

```
 [{"cid": 1, "cname": "Tien Hiep", "cmetaTitle": "tien-hiep", 
 "createDate": "May 6, 2018 1:04:58 PM "," createBy ":" Admin "," 
 modifiedDate ":" May 28, 2018 11:09:57 AM "," modifiedBy ":" Admin 
 "," cstatus " ..]
```

If I want to return the page type like:

```
    {
        "content":[
            {"cid": 1, "cname": "Tien Hiep", "cmetaTitle": "tien-hiep", "createDate": "May 6, 018 1:04:58 PM "," createBy ":" Admin "," modifiedDate ":" May 28, 2018 11:09:57 AM "," modifiedBy ":" Admin "," cstatus "}, 
            ...
        ],
        "last":false,
        "totalElements":10,
        "totalPages":4,
        "size":10,
        "number":0,
        "sort":null,
        "first":true,
    }
```

Can anybody help me fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If you add PageRequest with page limit and offset JPA will return the response as Page instead of List . SO you have to convert Page to List by using .getContent() before sending it to application . So that application will work without any problems.

```
PageRequest pageable= createPageRequest(page,size,sortBy,sortField); /** method to return PageRequest */
Page<TestData> pageList = testDataRepository.findAll(pageable);
List<TestData> testDataList = pageList.getContent();
```

Change the return type to List and add @Produces("application/json") so the API will return data as json.

If you use maven add jax-rs or jersey dependency